# Multiple outgoing connections from Tor browser

Tags: security

I see a lot of unknown outgoing connections from tor.exe to different IP addresses (about 6-7) every time Tor browser first connects to Internet after its installing. Only Tor entry guard remains with the following connections to Internet. Is it normal for Tor browser? What are these IP addresses? Is it possible to forbid them in my firewall and leave only Tor entry guard for higher security?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to connect with the Tor network you need to have some IP addresses from nodes that can accept your connection. This information is provided by the Tor Directory Nodes. I don't know how many connections are made but at least this gives you an idea about what it could be.